# how to disable git message about git initial branch name

Tags: git

I understand Microsoft recently changed the initial branch name in the github repositories, but now when I run "git init" on my computer I get a yellow alert message explaining that I can change the initial branch name to "master ". . some other name. And that makes me uncomfortable and does not let me work at ease because I see a yellow message and by default I read because it catches my attention and that distracts me.

Now how to disable that message?

I don't have the slightest intention of changing the default setting of the branch name because to be honest that's kind of silly.

Comment: Changing `master` is some stupid political over-correctness IMHO. Any body will return his/her "master of arts"?

Comment: @U.Windl: many would agree but SO is not a place for such discussions

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I agree

Comment: How does what Microsoft does with their branch names affect what happens when you run `git init`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: Microsoft is almighty. Seriously, newer versions of git ineed produce a waring: `hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
`

Comment: So, the message that `git init` shows tells you what you have to do so that the message is not shown anymore. @AlexAlbuja have you tried to do what the message says?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I initially thought about it, but I ran "git config --global init.defaultBranch <master>" (my error), it's just that sometimes you are so into something and overlook those errors

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk if SO is not the place where we talk about politics, why git warns such hint within ? git itself introduces such controversial debate into the open source world, It's git who should be ashamed of itself, not us.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Newer versions of Git indeed produce a warning when initting a new
repository:

```
$ git init
warning: templates not found in /home/ja/share/git-core/templates
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint:
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint:
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint:
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/new/.git/
```

> Now how to disable that message?

It says right there:

```
To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint:
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
```

So if you want to keep using master:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch master
```

BTW,

> I understand Microsoft recently changed the initial branch name in
> the github repositories

Microsoft is big and powerful but it doesn't own Git.

Comment: I initially thought about it, but I ran "git config --global init.defaultBranch <master>" (my error), it's just that sometimes you are so into something and overlook those errors, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Specify the default branch in the init command without changing the configuration

```
git -c init.defaultBranch=master init
```